# Conversion of daterangepicker text to datetime input

Tags: javascript, datetime, cakephp-3.0, daterangepicker

I'm attempting to do a conversion of the text inputs which DateRangePicker uses to a datetime input as all my dates are in datetime format. My code is as follows:

```
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('input[name="date_start"]').daterangepicker({
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        locale: {
            cancelLabel: 'Clear'
        },
        format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
        startDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        endDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        minDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    });

    $('input[name="date_start"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
        $("#date_start").val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
        $("#date_end").val(picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    });

    $('input[name="date_start"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val('');
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 70px;">
    <?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
    <?php $this->Form->templates([
        'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group">{{content}}</div>',
        'inputContainerError' => '<div class="error" style="color:red;">{{content}}{{error}}</div>'
    ]);?>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="container col-sm-12" style="border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid;" >
            <?= $this->Form->create() ?>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?= $this->Form->input('date_start', ['class'=>'form-control', 'type'=>'text', 'label'=>'Session Dates',
                'placeholder'=>'Please select the start and end dates for your session.']);?>
            </div>

            <input type="text" name="date_start" id="date_start" value="" />
            <input type="text" name="date_end" id="date_end" value="" />

                        <input id='date_start' class='form_control' name='date_start'/>
            <input id='date_end' class='form_control' name='date_end'/>

            <script>
                <?php $date_starttext ?> = document.getElementById('date_start').value;
                <?php $date_endtext ?> = document.getElementById('date_end').value;
                <?php $date_startdt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y', $date_starttext)->format('Y-M-d'); ?>
                <?php $date_enddt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y', $date_endtext)->format('Y-M-d'); ?>
            </script>

            <div>
            <?= $this->Form->input('sessions.0.date_start', ['class'=>'form-control', 'type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>$date_startdt]); ?>
            </div>
            <div>
            <?= $this->Form->input('sessions.0.date_end', ['class'=>'form-control', 'type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>$date_enddt]);?>
            </div>

            <input type="text" name="sessions.0.date_start" id="sessions.0.date_start" value="" />
            <input type="text" name="date_start5" id="sessions.0.date_start" value="" />
            <input type="text" name="sessions.0.date_end" id="date_end5" value="" />

            <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2">
          </div>
          </div>
```

However, when I try to load the page with this code, I'm getting this error:

> Call to a member function format() on boolean

And the error message refers to this line:

```
<?php $date_startdt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y', '$date_starttext')->format('Y-M-d'); ?>
```

I'm not entirely sure what's wrong. Presumably the DateTime:createFromFormat for below it also has the same error.

Comment: This is your problem `'$date_starttext'` single quotes don't substitute variable , values remove the quotes around or use double quotes do same for `'$date_endtext'`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, DateTime::createFromFormat method returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure, so I'm guessing you are passing an invalid string for parsing, and the method returns you boolean with value false.